# When trying to navigate to a view that has Authorization attribute I get redirected to the login page, even though my role is SuperAdmin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-roles

I am having an issue with Authorizing roles, I am logging in and my role is SuperAdmin, but when I test to see if I can get to the administration view, which has Authorization(Roles="SuperAdmin"), but when I type in the view into my address bar, I get redirected to the Login View and if I try to login from there and go to the Administration view I am still getting redirected back to the Login

My login method is this

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        PasswordHasher ph = new PasswordHasher();
        IdentityClassesEntities ICE = new IdentityClassesEntities();

        var user = ICE.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Email == model.Email).Select(s => s.PasswordHash).FirstOrDefault();

        var result = ph.VerifyHashedPassword(user, model.Password).ToString();


        //string h = result.ToString();
        if (result == "Success")
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication
              .SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            Claim claim1 = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email);
            Claim[] claims = new Claim[] { claim1 };
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity =
              new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, claimsIdentity);

            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

            AWSessionClass ASC = new Models.AWSessionClass();

            ASC.IdInSession(model.Email);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
               return View(model);
        }

    }
```

Once I login I get directed to a main page, which is correct, but when I try to get Administration/Administration, I have this in my AdministrationController

```
[Authorize(Roles="SuperAdmin")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    //Bunch of other code
}
```

It just redirects me to a login screen, I even tried

```
[Authorize(Roles="SuperAdmin")]
public ActionResult Administration()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But the same thing happens.

Can anyone point out why this is happening with the code I have provided or do I need to add more information?

Comment: If you remove the `Roles="SuperAdmin"` part, does it work?

Comment: @DavidG, If i do remove the Roles="SuperAdmin", then I have no problem getting to the view, I need to have the Authorization because only Admins and SuperAdmin Roles are allowed to navigate to that view, the other roles I have are Manufacturer and Dealer, and those Roles aren't allowed to get to that view, and Manufacturers can't get to a dealer view and a dealer can't get to a Manufacturer view, but an Admin or a SuperAdmin can view either of those other views.

Comment: I'm guessing there is some conflict in the role management. What happens if you add `<roleManager enabled="false" />` to your web.config?

Comment: @DavidG, I don't have that in my webconfig

Comment: I know, I said to add it :)

Comment: @DavidG, where does it get added in the webconfig

Comment: @DavidG, same thing...What I did just notice though that I don't have RoleManager implemented in my IdentityConfig. I guess that could be a reason why?